# Proxying response from Location header on Apache Httpd as if it was normal resource

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

I have Apache Httpd configuration which is used as standard reverse proxy. I add some headers and forward request to AWS API Gateway (`api_gw_vpc_endpoint`)

```
<Location /server>

  RequestHeader set x-apigw-api-id "${api_gw_id}"
  RequestHeader set x-api-key "${api_gw_key_secret}"

  ProxyPass ${api_gw_vpc_endpoint}
  ProxyPassReverse ${api_gw_vpc_endpoint}

</Location>
```

Most of the responses from are regular. It means `200` response code and content. It is simply proxied to the client. But for one particular url `/server/bigdata` the response is `302 (FOUND)` and in the `Location` header I get info about new location of the resource. The problem is, the client has no access to this new location. So I cannot simply forward this request to it, because it cannot download the resource. This access however I have on the Apache Httpd server which acts as this proxy.

My question is: how (if this is even possible) could I configure my extra location `/server/bigdata` to:

- download the resource given in the `Location` header
- return it to the client with `200` response code and content (+ headers)

```
<Location /server/bigdata>

  RequestHeader set x-apigw-api-id "${api_gw_id}"
  RequestHeader set x-api-key "${api_gw_key_secret}"

  ProxyPass ${api_gw_vpc_endpoint}
  ProxyPassReverse ???????

  ???????
  ???????

</Location>
```

**Solution #1** (not working)
I tried to remove ProxyPassReverse and use Header directive to manipulate the answer - but cannot process the request defined in the `Location` header on the Apache level.

This didn't work - I saw no changes in the requests processing.
`ProxyPassReverse %{resp:Location}`

**Solution #2** (not verified but should work)
Using CGI scripts to handle such request. I thought only I could do this without CGI. That's why I created this question.